# Is there a way to set "today" as default due date in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I am using a Trello board for my daily plan. I would like all newly added cards to be added with current date as due date. I know I can add cards and afterward I can set the date, I am even using the "d" shortcut to speed things up.

I was wondering if there is a way to automate it even more.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via Trello API. Just use `POST /1/cards` method to add card and specified `due` argument.

I do not think that it is possible to achieve this functionality in current version of Trello GUI.

See: [Adding card](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#post-1-cards)